# How To Pause/Enable Keywords With Google Ads API V14 and Python?

Tags: python-3.x, google-ads-api

Does anyone know how to use the google ads api V14 to enable/pause a keyword? If so i'd really appreciate your help.

I have this code which works well for other versions of google ads api but not v14 as I keep getting this error:

> ERROR:root:'GoogleAdsClient' object has no attribute 'types'

See my code below:

```
def update_google_ads(query_results, customer_id, developer_token):
# Get the authenticated Google Ads API client
credentials = get_google_ads_credentials(creds_file)
client = GoogleAdsClient(credentials=credentials, developer_token=developer_token)
# Get campaign criterion service
campaign_criterion_service = client.get_service("CampaignCriterionService")
try:
for result in query_results:
query = result["Query"]
status = result["Result"]
# Create the keyword criterion
keyword_criterion = client.types.KeywordCriterion()
keyword_criterion.keyword.text = query
keyword_criterion.keyword.match_type = client.enums.KeywordMatchTypeEnum.EXACT
# Update the status of the keyword criterion
if status == "Enable":
keyword_criterion.keyword.status = client.types.KeywordStatus.ENABLED
else:
keyword_criterion.keyword.status = client.types.KeywordStatus.PAUSED
# Prepare the campaign criterion operation
operation = client.types.CampaignCriterionOperation()
operation.update = keyword_criterion
# Execute the mutate operation
response = campaign_criterion_service.mutate_campaign_criterion(
customer_id=customer_id, operations=[operation]
)
logging.info(f"Updated keyword '{query}' to {status} for customer {customer_id}")
except Exception as e:
logging.error(e)
```

Thanks in advance

Mark